# Can multiple instances of SignalR be configured to use a different message bus for different instances

Tags: asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am running a site in which I am using SignalR with a custom scaleout backplane that allows us to push out real-time data to users connected to any of our load balanced web servers.

I recently found out that the Kendo UI components for MVC (which we use for other site features) can be configured to use SignalR rather than AJAX for binding with the data model. It seems like using web sockets via SignalR could potentially offer a performance boost over using AJAX as we are now. However, I would ideally like to let our kendo components access a SignalR instance that only uses whatever web server they connect to rather than using the instance with the scaleout backplane since that would involve a lot of overgead that isn't necessary for that data binding.

I should mention that there would be cases where we would have one page with one partial view that uses one SignalR configuration and another partial view that uses the other.

Is this something that can be done? If so, are there recommended ways of going about doing so?

Comment: Since the configuration is global - applies to all hubs - you will need two web applications, one for each hub(scale configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely certain about your approach but you can of course have 2 SignalR servers using different kinds of backplanes and connect to the 2 servers from a client. You would have to though look into how to handle cross-domain requests with SignalR.